# Piece values on nonstandard boards

Tags: chess-variants, point-value, reference-request

[Inspiration.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39003/what-are-the-piece-values-in-chess-coms-four-player-chess)

For the moment, a nonstandard nxn board suffices. Very obviously, with growing n the long-range pieces become stronger with respect to short range ones. (Also, other effects come in play, e.g. the Q can't regularly win against a R if n is large enough.) Does any research on assigning piece values on a nonstandard nxn board exist?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one idea.

1. Create an engine that can play on that nxn board.
2. Expose the piece value as option for tuning.
3. Conduct piece value optimization using [optuna](https://github.com/optuna/optuna) hyperparameter optimization framework or other framework. Typical example is the [optuna game parameter tuner](https://github.com/fsmosca/Optuna-Game-Parameter-Tuner).

After some trials you will be able to get a decent piece values.